# How to paint on linux graphical console?

Tags: linux, console, framebuffer

I need to display QR codes on graphical console on Linux. I am using qemu. Can you give me a sample code of painting something on graphical console or a hint how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just write a bitmap file and display it using [fbi](http://linux.bytesex.org/fbida/)?